# Simple PDE with Neumann BC

Tags: differential-equations

i have looked up solutions for my problems but they are either not related or to complicated, since my problem is rather simple:

I want to impose 2 Dirichlet and 2 Neumann BCs on a rectangle. The analytical solution for the problem is known for comparison: u(x,y)=x1*x2
My first approach would be:

```
bcdiri = {u[1, x2] == x2, u[x1, 0] == 0};
bcneu = {(-D[u[x1, x2], x1] /. x1 -> 0) == -x2, (D[u[x1, x2], x2] /. 
  x2 -> 1) == x1};
NDSolveValue[{Derivative[0,2][u][x1,x2]+Derivative[2,0][u][x1,x2]==0}~Join~bcdiri~Join~bcneu,u[x1,x2],{x1,0,1},{x2,0,1}]
```

But this does not work.
I also tried this:

```
bcneu = NeumannValue[-x2, x1 == 0];
```

Which works somehow...but the other Neumann BC is not included...Lists or something like && also does not work.
So...how to do it?

Thanks alot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check help [page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html)  on `NeumannValue`.

```
sol = NDSolve[{Derivative[0, 2][u][x1, x2] + 
     Derivative[2, 0][u][x1, x2] == -NeumannValue[-x2, x1 == 0] + 
     NeumannValue[x1, x2 == 1], u[1, x2] == x2, u[x1, 0] == 0}, 
  u[x1, x2], {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}];
Plot3D[u[x1, x2] /. sol, {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]